How do I effectively filter locations in my database without having to loop through it manually?
In my DRF project, I have a model structured like this
class ServiceLocation(models.Model):
    '''
    Represents a location where an internet service is offered
    '''
    SERVICE_TYPES = [
        ("wifi", 'wifi'),
        ("fibre", "fibre"),
        ("p2p/ptmp", "p2p/ptmp")
    ]

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField()


    # Location
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=15)

    # Service
    service = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=SERVICE_TYPES, null=False, blank=False)
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.service} by {self.operator}"


and I'm trying to filter this instances of this model with their relative proximity to given coordinate.
My view is structured like this

class CloseServiceLocations(View):
    def get(self, request):
        lat = request.GET.get('lat', 6.748134)
        lng = request.GET.get('lng', 3.633301)
        distance = request.GET.get('distance', 10)  # Default distance to 10 if not provided

        # if lat is None or lng is None:
        #     # return JsonResponse({'error': 'Latitude and Longitude are required parameters.'}, status=400)


        try:
            lat = float(lat)
            lng = float(lng)
            distance = float(distance)
        except ValueError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid latitude, longitude, or distance provided.'}, status=400)

        # Create a Point object representing the provided latitude and longitude
        user_location = Point(lng, lat, srid=4326)

        

        # Calculate the distance in meters (Django's Distance function uses meters)
        distance_in_meters = distance * 1000  
        close_service_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.annotate(
            # Convert longitude and latitude fields to floats
            longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()),
            latitude_float=Cast('latitude', FloatField())
        ).annotate(
            # Create Point object using converted longitude and latitude
            location=Point(F('longitude_float'), F('latitude_float'), srid=4326)
        ).annotate(
            # Calculate distance
            distance=Distance('location', user_location)
        ).filter(distance__lte=distance_in_meters)
    # Serialize the queryset to JSON
        serialized_data = [{'id': location.id,
                            'description': location.description,
                            'operator': location.operator.name,
                            'address': location.address,
                            'latitude': location.latitude,
                            'longitude': location.longitude,
                            'service': location.service,
                            'speed': location.speed} for location in close_service_locations]

        return JsonResponse(serialized_data, safe=False)

    def post(self, request):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Method not allowed'}, status=405)


where i try to annotate a new attribute "location" so i can take advantage of from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions's Distance method to calculate the distance instead of looping through and calculating the Haversine distance manually which was my initial approach.
when i run this, i get Server Error message which I'm almost sure is not from my views.
In an attempt to fix this, I broke my views down with into sections and added print statements to see what part was causing it to break
        print("Annotating QS with lon/lat float... ")
        close_service_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.annotate(
            # Convert longitude and latitude fields to floats
            longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()),
            latitude_float=Cast('latitude', FloatField())
        )
        print("LON/LAT float annotation complete")
       
        print("Annotating QS with location point... ")
        print("Size: ", len(close_service_locations))
       

        close_service_locations = close_service_locations.annotate(
            # Create Point object using converted longitude and latitude
            location=Point('longitude_float', 'latitude_float', srid=4326)
        )
        print("Location point annotation complete")

        print("Annotating QS with relative distance... ")
        close_service_locations = close_service_locations.annotate(
            # Calculate distance
            distance=Distance('location', user_location)
        )
        print("Distance annotation complete")

I noticed the print("Annotating QS with lon/lat float... ") block runs successfully in no time but it breaks in the print("Annotating QS with location point... ") block where i try to annotate the QS with location attribute
At some point, I got an error that says "Invalid parameters given for Point initialization." which made me add the print("Annotating QS with lon/lat float... ") block to force all Decimalfiled objects into floats.
I also tried looping through the close_service_locations manually to see if I have a service location with an invalid latitude or longitude with this
for i in range(len(close_service_locations)):
            print(i)
            location=Point(close_service_locations[i].longitude_float, close_service_locations[i].latitude_float, srid=4326)


Surprisingly, this ran successfully.
But I still dont know how to get my view to work successfully past that point.
This is the error i keep getting
Annotating QS with lon/lat float...
LON/LAT float annotation complete
Annotating QS with location point...

[13/Apr/2024 04:49:30] "GET /directory/close-service-locations/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 

No Django Error page on the browser detailing the cause, just a big Server Error
I also tried looping through the service-locations manually and adding the location attribute and printing the index maybe I could get an hint of what is breaking my code or if there is service location whose longitude and altitude pair couldn't be converted to a Point object but I still got the same error


you have to read that error or look at the logs to identify in which line your code is breaking

@shivankgtm Thanks for looking into this with me. As I mentioned, the only error I got on my console is Server Error, with no details so I don’t know how else to identify the cause of the error.
But from the logging I did, I could tell the error is thrown when I try to annotate the queryset with location(Point field) attribute from the longitude_float and latitude_float attributes

the server tells you exact line on which it is coming. just scroll on that you ll identify the line or please paste the error

@shivankgtm This is running on my PC. The only remote resource is the postgres db and  server isn't returning any error detail except the E500
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.    

Center:  SRID=4326;POINT (3.633301 6.748134)
Search Radius(meters):  10000.0
LON/LAT float annotation complete   
Annotating QS with location point...
Size:  15433
[13/Apr/2024 11:38:28] "GET /directory/close-service-locations/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145


sorry mate, really want to help but you are providing only half information. try to paste error add screenshot link

@shivankgtm I have edited the question and added a screenshot of the returned error. I tried looping through the service-locations manually and adding the location attribute and printing the index maybe I could get an hint of what is breaking my code or if there is service location whose longitude and altitude pair couldn't be converted to a Point object but i still got the same error

your code seems to be breaking in following like, add a try and catch to see what's happening
            # Create Point object using converted longitude and latitude
            location=Point('longitude_float', 'latitude_float', srid=4326)
        )```

Thanks. I logged the exception.
Invalid parameters given for Point initialization.

Now, I have an idea what's breaking my code. Pinpointing the exact location out of 15433 in my db is the new problem. I tried to fix this with this block of code where i converted the lng/lat to float
        close_service_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.annotate(
            # Convert longitude and latitude fields to floats
            longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()),
            latitude_float=Cast('latitude', FloatField())
        )

which ran successfully

what is your Point class ?

The Point class from django.contrib.gis.geos

somewhere in your data your following validation is getting false.Latitude ranges from -90 to 90 degrees, and longitude ranges from -180 to 180 degrees you somewhere going above or below these values.

I just checked my service locations in the admin panel with the following filters to confirm lat/lng' validity
admin/directory/servicelocation/?longitude__lte=-180
admin/directory/servicelocation/?longitude__gte=180
admin/directory/servicelocation/?latitude__lte=-90
admin/directory/servicelocation/?longitude__gte=90
There are no invalid lng/lat pairs

Consider simply using a PointField instead of all of these conversions.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, I'll be building the v.2 of my API soon and I'll definitely be using the PointField to avoid all these and enjoy more GeoDjango functionalities.

I devised a different approach based on how precise the decimal digits on the coordinates of google maps are and it worked.
    def get(self, request):
        lat = request.GET.get('lat', 8.464134)
        lng = request.GET.get('lng', 4.454301)
        distance = request.GET.get('distance', 10)  # Default distance to 10 km if not provided

        try:
            lat = float(lat)
            lng = float(lng)
            distance = float(distance)
        except ValueError:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid latitude, longitude, or distance provided.'}, status=400)

        # Define the approximate distance difference in degrees (assuming 1 degree is approximately 111 km)
        diff = distance / 111    
        
        print("Getting SLs .....")
        close_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.filter(latitude__gte=(lat-diff), latitude__lte=(lat+diff), longitude__gte=(lng-diff), longitude__lte=(lng+diff), )

        print("Close locations length ", len(close_locations))
        serialized = ServiceLocationSerializer(close_locations, many=True)

        print(serialized.data)
        return Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK) 


In your following code you are providing strings(longitude_floatlatitude_float and latitude_float) to Point class.
close_service_locations = close_service_locations.annotate(
    # Create Point object using converted longitude and latitude
     location=Point('longitude_float', 'latitude_float', srid=4326)
   )


you might be thinking that you are creating those value above but that's in line longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()), but in following annotation it is considering as just string.
you can trying following to make it work.
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import F
close_service_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.annotate(
            # Convert longitude and latitude fields to floats
            longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()),
            latitude_float=Cast('latitude', FloatField()),
            location=Point(F('longitude_float'), F('latitude_float'), srid=4326)
            # in the same code.
        )

EDIT:
An Another way to do this is to use Python instead of Django.
close_service_locations = ServiceLocation.objects.annotate(
    # Convert longitude and latitude fields to floats
    longitude_float=Cast('longitude', FloatField()),
    latitude_float=Cast('latitude', FloatField())
)
service_location_mapping = {}
for service in close_service_locations:
    location = Point(service.longitude_float, service.latitude_float, srid=4326)
    distance = Distance(location, user_location)
    service_location_mapping[service] = {
        'distance': distance,
        'service': service
    }


This throws the same error.

@O.GBellz, I have edited, should be fine now.

The version where you passed longitude_float and latitude_float directly into the Point class didn't work. It threw "longitude_float isn;t defined".
The latest version with (F) to refrence both fields throws the same error. I've actually tried this before.

strange, works fine for me. ll look at this later.

Thanks a lot. I'll keep trying it and other variations of this solution.

Or might can just use Python instead of Django, was reading docs for point and it might have some trouble when we pass it to DB.

This could work, but it means I'd have to loop through all the Service Locations in my db (A large database which would increase over time) which is something I'd trying to avoid.

I've been reading up on how precise coordinates are on Google map and I'm considering a different approach where I create a boundary for both longitude and latitude that matched the desired distance and filter the QS with that boundary.
Something like this:
ServiceLocation.objects.filter(lat_gte={max_lat}&lat_lte={min_lat}&lng_gte={max_lng}&lng_lte={min_lng})

I'm still working on this though
